# Well defined operator between $L_p$ and $L_q$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I have a doubt which can be summarized in the following question:

> Let $(\Omega , A,\mu)$ be a probability space and $F: \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function such that $\|F\|_p<\infty$ with $p\in[1,\infty)$. Now if we define the function $g(x)=\int_\Omega f(y)F(y,x)d\mu(y)$ and $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$.
>
> 1. Does $g$ belong to $L_p(\Omega)$ for every $f\in L_q(\Omega)$?
> 2. Does $g$ belng to $L_q(\Omega)$ for every $f\in L_p(\Omega)$?

**My attempt:**

I have not come too far but I expose my attempt. Concretely, I am trying to use the following property which follows from Hölder inequality:
$$\int_\Omega \left|\int_\Omega f(y)F(x,y) d\mu(y) \right|^r d\mu(x)\leq \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \left|f(y)F(x,y)\right|^r d\mu(y)  d\mu(x),\;\forall r\geq1.$$
However, I don't know how to use this property to involve the norms of $f$ and $F$ in each item, I have tried to use the Young's inequality but it have not worked to me.

Any help will be wellcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $|g(x)| \leq (\int |f(x)|^{q})^{1/q} (\int |f(y,x)|^{p} dy)^{1/p}$ so $|g(x)|^{p} \leq (\int |f(x)|^{q})^{p/q} (\int |F(y,x)|^{p} dy)$. Integrating we get $\int |g(x)|^{p} \leq \|f\|_q^{p} \|F\|_p^{p}$ so $g \in L^{p}$.
2. is fasle. Here is a hint: take $F(y,x)=\phi(y)\psi(x)$ where $\phi, \psi \in L^{p}, \phi \in L^{q}, \psi \notin L^{q}$ and $\int f \phi \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Really clarifying!